# Display 3 level taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm a bit confused how to handle this kind of output.
I suppose to display three level taxonomies. When a term is clicked i still need to display his level brothers but also his children's...
The posts needs to be displayed only when i click the third level taxonomy term.

Please see the mockup below.
[image: three level taxonomies]

Answer (score 0):

Here is general guideline to get what you need.
Use `get_term()` to get 1st, 2nd and 3rd level terms.Documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters).

**1st Level:** you can display this list of terms directly in php as follows

```
$taxonomy = "SOME_TAXONOMY";
$terms = get_terms([
     'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
     'parent' => 0,
     ]);


if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { ?>
<ul>
    <?php 
    foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**2nd / 3rd Level Terms**
After displaying 1st level terms, you should use ajax action to get child terms of clicked parent term. Pass `id` of parent term to ajax action function. Documentation for using Ajax with Wordpress is [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Code for ajax action should look like this.

```
function wp_ajax_child_terms_action(){

    $taxonomy = "SOME_TAXONOMY";
    $parent = $_GET['id_of_parent_from_ajax'];
    $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'parent' => $parent,
     ]);


    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { ?>
       <ul>
           <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
            <li>
                 <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>

<?php }  ?>
```

I hope this may help you start.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
On one hand this is a useful solution but on the other hand i need  a unique url for each and every term click on all three level.

Comment: You can handle this in JS  while making ajax call. Urls will act as fallback if JS is disabled on visitor browser.

Comment: just asking, is there a way to accomplish same results without using ajax?

Comment: Yes, but in that case page will be refreshed on every click. To get same result without ajax, append `GET` parameters to every term's link. For example for parent term you can append `?get-children-of=<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>` and to second level append `?get-grand-children-of=<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>` and for 3rd level append `?get-posts-of=<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>`. And finally use conditional statements like `if(isset($_GET['**APPENDED_PARAMETER**'])){` before displaying each level and post.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)